# How to get MasterId itemid printed only once for the list of items in the order table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables
Order_tbl
[image]

The items master
[image]

I wanted to write a query to return as below in MySQL 5.6

[image]

Thanks for your help in advance

SELECT  CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY t.inventory_order_id ORDER BY t.inventory_order_id ) <> 1
THEN NULL
ELSE t.inventory_order_id
END inventory_order_id ,
t.Contents
FROM    inventory_order_line_item AS t;

This throws me up an error in Apache Superset